# Problem installing Apache (LAMP)

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, lamp

I am trying to install LAMP and after this command:

```
sudo ufw app info “Apache Full”
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: Invalid profile name
```

I'm following [these](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu) instructions.

Any advice?

Comment: Use straight double quotes `"` instead of the typographical slanted quotes `“”` you copied from the website. Actually websites shouldn't use them in code at all, but graphic designers are sometimes quite persistent.

Comment: @Jos: Thanks! I got over that step, problem solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

`sudo ufw app info “Apache Full”`
(typographical slanted queotes), use:

`sudo ufw app info "Apache Full"`
(straight double quotes), as per [Jos](https://askubuntu.com/users/149708/jos).